# Tcl rest interface POST with query

Tags: rest, post, tcl

Using the tcllib rest package in interface "mode", how would one POST a key/value pairs while also passing key/value pairs in the query string?

Given `one=foo, two=bar` for the query string, and `three=baz, four=qux` for the form submission, how would the config array be structured and how would the call be implemented?

Comment: You must have done some experimentation: what have you tried?